# Creating a reference array from another array

Tags: c#, arrays

My task is the next (in C#):
I have a List with thousands of elements - each student has a name and an age (from 7-18). The important thing that this list is ordered, by the age, ascending. So the very first element would be like some of the 7 years old students. I have to write a search function soon (it doesn't really matter now), but in order to make the search function faster, I've been told to make a reference array which points to every first element of ages in my Students list, so actually this new array would contain 11 elements (let's say we have at least one child from each age group, which is most likely) since I would store the first elements of each years.

So whenever I would have to find a student who is for example 16 years old, I could start searching on the ref array first, get to the 16 yo student really fast,  which points to Student list's 16 years old student's first element right on the spot without pointless iterating. My question is, how can I tell my `Student[] refArray()` to make a reference to every first "group of ages" in student list?

```
static Student[] refArray(List<Student> list_in)
    {
        int i = 7;
        Student[] refArray = new Student[11];
        // the size of the array is 11 since I'm assuming to get at least
        // 1 student of each age groups, but I could just use a List or anything

        foreach (Student stud in list_in)
        {
            if (stud.age == i)
            {
                refArray[i++] = stud;
            }
        }

        return refArray;
    }
```

I'm really sure this is code is as wrong as a bad code could be, but I have no idea how to solve this the easiest way. Another problem that I really don't know what if I found a first student with that age, how to make a ref which points to that object in student list...

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough to be answered: please reword/rewrite it to make it clearer. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a dictionary on year, index?

Comment: @Alex: what is not clear? I can't see it in your comment.

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally wrong with your code. Are you getting an error? Or are you looking for a code review (which is another SE site).

Comment: Why aren't you using a 'better' data structure, like a `Dictionary`?  `Dictionaries` work with a `Key/Value` pairing so look-ups are easy.  If this list grows, using an `array` will cripple you because you have to declare their size at _initialization_.

Comment: (I suspect this is a homework assignment, and that he's not supposed to use a Dictionary yet)

Comment: As I understand, the reference array should contain indices of first students of given age, not students themselves.

Comment: I am not supposed to use anything else than List. That's what they said.
Jon B: well... I am still not sure if it works correctly. What if I miss one age group? For example there isn't any student who is 16 years old. It won't really work then.

Comment: @PatrickHofman actually, on second thought, I think it's clearer than I originally thought. However, the grammar isn't the best, to the point where it's difficult to understand in some places. Also, the initial paragraph (to me) has too much information. These might seem like little things, but together, they make the question difficult to understand.

Comment: Ulugbek Umirov: wouldn't it mess up things if I would store only indexes? What if I add new students to the list.. Since it is ordered, it would make changes in the indexes as well.

Comment: A "reference array" is not how to solve this problem in C#, use the provided lookup classes/functions instead.

Comment: The task clearly tells me to "create a reference array". :(
Alex: sorry for that, I'm beginner and it's really hard to explain these kind of things.

Comment: @egyeneskanyar Sorry. I've edited your post and fixed the things that made me downvote it in the first place, and undid my downvote.

Comment: @egyeneskanyar, As you pointed out, indices will break if you insert into the list. Holding a reference to the "first" student is going to have the *same exact problem* because there is no guarantee that it will remain "first". You need to actually group the items into separate collections (as in a Dictionary or Lookup) to have a truly reasonable (as opposed to contrived) solution. A dictionary/hash is the industry standard for this kind of problem.

Comment: @egyeneskanyar How reference to `Student` will help you in search? If you have index, you can search starting from given index. If you have Student, you have just Student without any information about its position in the list. In case of list modification you need to rebuild/update reference array. BTW, since you're allowed to use only `List`s, why don't you make `List<List<Student>> groupedList = new List<List<Student>>()`?

Comment: Bradley: I just talked to one of my expert mate and he told me the same. Dict / hash. But the problem is, I'm not supposed to use those now. I may find the first elements as long as I don't edit the original students list afterwards... then my reference table worth nothing...
Alex: thank you :) I did not downvote you though

Comment: Ulugbek Umirov: "In case of list modification you need to rebuild/update reference array. BTW, since you're allowed to use only Lists, why don't you make List<List<Student>> groupedList = new List<List<Student>>()?"
I have no idea about that kind of list. By the way, as you said, upon modification, my ref array is useless. But what if I just update it at every search? I just call getRefArray(List<student> list) at each search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the answers so far are fairly sophisticated, using Linq.  Since you're not allowed to use dictionaries, I suppose you're not allowed to use Linq, either.  I think this answers the question in the intended spirit.  Note that I renamed the method to reduce name clashes:

```
static int[] GetRefArray(List<Student> list_in)
{
    int[] refArray = new int[11];

    int referenceIndex = 0;
    int dataIndex = 0;
    int currentAge = int.MinValue;

    foreach (Student stud in list_in)
    {
        if (stud.age != currentAge)
        {
            currentAge = stud.age;
            refArray[referenceIndex++] = dataIndex;
        }
        dataIndex++;
    }

    return refArray;
}
```

Now there are all sorts of problems with this approach, as mentioned in the comments.  There's an easy solution to handle the problem of list inserts: throw away the reference array whenever you insert into the list and recalculate the reference array whenever you need to use it:

```
//we're about to use refArray to improve our lookup performance
if (refArray == null)
    refArray = GetRefArray(studentList);
//use refArray here
```

and

```
//we're about to insert into the student list
refArray = null;
studentList.Insert(index, newStudent);
```

You could also modify the values in the refArray whenever you do an insert or remove.  That could be tricky to get right, however, so I would only do it if performance testing indicated that it was necessary (or if it's a class assignment).

Answer (score 3):

The least complicated/easiest to understand way to accomplish this would be to start by populating a `Dictonary<int, List<Student>>` and doing your look up from there. However, since you already have a list, you can create a `Lookup` by using `ToLookup`

```
var lookup = studentsList.ToLookup(s => s.Age);
```

Then you can index in just like a dictionary. For example, to get all students with age 8:

```
var age8Students = lookup[8];
```

Here is a good explanation of this function: [DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tolookup)

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I agree that a better data structure would be the best solution.  That said, you could use a LINQ query to do what you're looking at.  Assuming your list of students is already sorted by age (and presumably by some other category such as alphabetically by last name within the age groups).

Assuming a Student class similar to:

```
public class Student
{
   public int Age {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The code would be similar to:

```
var list = GetStudents();  // gets full list of students from somewhere, ordered by age, then name
var subList = new List<Student>();  // creates new empty list of students.

var ageList = list.Select(s => s.Age).Distinct().ToList();  // Gets a list of distinct age values
ageList.ForEach(s => subList.Add(list.First(p => p.Age == s)));
```

The variable subList would then contain a list of students with each student being the first in each age group.  Getting the list of distinct ages in your list of students gets only ages that have at least one student, so your list.First should never encounter an exception.

Of course, one drawback to this is that, if your master list of students changes, you'll need to regenerate your subList.